# "Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator" when passing an object's address

Tags: c++

Here is part of my code:

```
class A
{
  public:
  void init(classB& pObject);
  classB& _pObject;
}

void classA::init(classB& pObject)
{
  _pObject = pObject;
}

class B
{
  public:
  void init();
}

void classB::init()
{
  classA* pClassA = new classA;
  pClassA->init(&this);
}
```

I got 2 problems after compile:

1. `_pObject = pObject;`: No viable overloaded '='
2. `pClassA->init(&this);`: Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

I'm getting confused about these problems... How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a typo in the question. I assume that `A` and `classA` refer to the same class, ditto for `B` and `classB`.

1) One of the few differences between a reference and a pointer is that you cannot assign a different value to a reference once it's been initialised. So you just cannot assign to `_pObject`,  though you can initialise it in the initialisation list of the constructor for class `A`:

```
classA::classA(classB& object) : _pObject(object) // Correct
{
  // _pObject = object;        on the other hand, this would be incorrect
}
```

2) `&this` is the address of `this`, but you actually want a reference to the value pointed to by `this`. You need to use `*this` instead. Though we have already seen that there is no way to make function `classA::init` work with your current class design. If you really want to change the value of `_pObject` after the object has been constructed, you need to make it a `classB*` instead of a `classB&`.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should use `*this` in this context, as `&this` has the type of `ClassB**`, not `ClassB&`;

2) You can only initialize you reference member-variables in constructor:

```
classA::classA(classB& b) : _pObject(b)
{
}
```

(BTW I suppose that you ommitted `delete` statement just for brevity)

Comment: He has just answered in reverse order; answer 2) is for your problem 1.